# Is $y' = -ay^2 - b^2$ a nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I put the following equation into wolfram alpha
$$
y' = -ay^2 - b^2 
$$
(where $y$ is a function of x) and wolfram treated it as a nonlinear differential equation, but it can be solved as a linear differential equation by separation of variables, can it not?
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} &= -ay^2 - b^2\\
\frac{\mathrm{dy}}{-ay^2 -b^2} &= \mathrm{d}x\\
\int \frac{\mathrm{dy}}{-ay^2 -b^2} &= \int \mathrm{d}x\\
-\frac{\mathrm{atan\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}y}{b}\right)}}{\sqrt{a}b} + c &= x + c\\
y &= \frac{b\mathrm{tan}(-b\sqrt{a}x + c)}{\sqrt{a}}
\end{align}
Is there something wrong with this method, or is wolfram misinterpereting, or misevaluating the differential equation?

Comment: Separable and linear have not much to do with each other.

Comment: $y' = \sin y$ is separable but not linear, $y' = y + x$ is linear but not separable, $y' = y$ is both, $y' = x + \sin y$ is neither

Answer (score 3):

"Linear differential equations are the differential equations that are linear "in the unknown function and its derivatives."

Lets's check your equatio. If it is linear in $y$ which is the unknown function and its derivative $y'$, then the equation
$$(y_1+y_2)'=-a(y_1+y_2)^2-b^2\tag{1}$$
and the equation
$$y_1'+y_2'=-ay_1^2-ay_2^2-b^2\tag{2}$$
must be equal. I mean as expressions.
Substracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ and simplfying we get
$$ay_1y_2=0.$$
The equation is linear if $a=0$, otherwise it is non-linear.

Comment: One could argue that it should be $-2b^2$ in both instances. Otherwise it is affine linear combinations (coefficients sum to one) for inhomogeneous linear DE.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can have a

- a separable but nonlinear equation (e.g. $xdy = ydx$), or
- a linear but non-separable equation (e.g. $y'' + y' + y = 0$),

and yours is actually of the first kind (assume $a,b$ are constants, not functions of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get a linear DE out of this when treating it as Riccati DE due to the quadratic right side. Set $y=\frac{u'}{au}$ to get
$$
u''+ab^2u=0,
$$
which has well-known solutions.